# In this situation is it better to create a new class or to just copy paste a method?

Tags: c#, coding-style

Items of a ComboBox are getting pulled from some DB cache,etc.. This ComboBox has been used in one assembly and so there is the code for it in that assembly on how to load data. Now in a second assembly again I have the same combobox and again should be filled with the same items, so the code that loads items for this combobox is the same.

Now: I can either just copy paste that Load method in my new assembly OR I can add a reference to that assembly and create an instance of the class that this method is in it and then call that method. ( its methods are not static in that class)

Which approach do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both assemblies are still in use (i.e. subject to later changes), then obviously the import + use the same class. If that method ever needs changing you need to do it in two places. It's a maintenance nightmare.

If the other assembly is "abandoned" (will never be changed again), I guess you could get away with just copying the code.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could have a "shared class" which contains code which can be used in both assembly's in the event that you have more instances of this scenario?

E.g. `Shared.PopulateLocatons(cmbLocations)` so this function contains the code to populate locations but is part of a shared library that can be called from any assembly?

No point duplicating code if you don't need too :)

Answer (score 4):

Broadly speaking, I'd advocate the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle. Unless there is a really good reason not to, don't duplicate code - create a helper class or some other shared code device where you can put the code, then call it from both places. This way if a change is made, it only needs to be made once, and if a 3rd/4th/nth use becomes necessary you won't need to have 3/4/n duplicates of the same code.

Answer (score 1):

This is highly subjective. For one method, I'd just copy-paste, but be on the lookout -- if you later find that you want to use more from that assembly, then you might want to add a reference (and refactor the copy-paste).